# When to truncate strings longer than the storage location allows?

Tags: truncate

Let's say I have a function that inserts records into a database table with string fields of limited length. In general, at what point should I be truncating strings that are too long for the storage location, in the insert function itself, or at every point in the code where it's called?

(I'm assuming here that truncation of strings that are too long is more desirable than having an exception thrown.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it depends on where the function is and how accessible it is.

If it's a private function that just makes up your own SQL library then you can probably get away with truncating it in the function.

If it's in a library that, say, your team at work all use then perhaps you need to at least parse the string before attempting to insert it.

If it's a public API, then you shouldn't be silently truncating anything - throw a meaningful exception instead.

Comment: I'm afraid that simply throwing an exception will result in problems at a later point because of lazy programming… I.e., I'm expecting the programmers who will use this function are likely to forget to test with long strings.

Comment: @Protectorone In which case, they'll be glad you threw an exception, surely! If you didn't, they'd never know their string had been truncated!

Answer (score 1):

This should sit in the insert function - it's specific to the database implementation rather than the calling application. If you manage to change your data structure, you don't want to have to go back through all the client code to ensure the full string is used.

Answer (score 0):

As per Widor, but may I also add:

Your application should ideally be structured so that there is a distinct data layer that separates the rest of your code from the database and its implementation logic.

In high traffic systems you will ideally want to limit the amount of data passing back and forth between the database and your code, hence data validation should be performed by your data layer BEFORE passing it on to your database. It is here that you can raise a meaningful exception for your business logic to handle.

The object data presented by the data layer need bear no relation to what is actually stored in or by the database. For instance it may present a data object class that is actually a composite of data stored in several tables.

The data layer itself can be structured in such a way that it can handle different database implementations.

I have used a factory pattern in the past that has allowed me to switch between SQL, MySQL databases, XML file storage and compiled test data as required at runtime without the need for recompilation.

**edit**
Your application data layer is the interface between your application code e.g. business logic and GUI, and your database.

The business logic will trigger the data layer to update the database with your string.

In your example the data layer contains your update function.

You can validate the string, truncate it if too long, and then update the database (through stored procedure call or direct write for instance) within that function if you wish.

In reality you'll have many strings that will have to be restricted to the same length, so it is advisable to have the validation performed by a seperate function to save duplicating code.

Also you may wish to validate/truncate the string and notify the user/calling code of this without writing the data to the database.

Essentially though this is performed by your application data layer code, which may be encapsulated within a class library/dll for instance and not left to the database to handle nor the business logic (other than to react to any error event/response fed back).

Comment: Let's assume that the function I'm referring to in the questions, is _in_ the Data Layer. Or rather, are you saying that the truncation should happen inside the Data Layer?

Comment: If your insert function is in the data layer and not the application business logic or the database e.g. stored procedure, then yes. See my edited answer.